Using Python Scalene to profile all functions / modules called
I am trying to profile my python code. I looked at Scalene, for which I would need to run scalene main.py in my cmd. However main.py also has some custom imported functions, from other files like processing.py and get_data.py. Scalene only shows a report of the main.py instead of all functions that are used in the code.
I don't know how to get a proper insight in the memory usage of the code.
I have tried to include multiple files as extra parameters as well as using a decorator (@profile), which doesn't seem to do anything.

Have you tried --profile-all (usually useful in conjunction with --profile-only and --profile-exclude)? (See scalene --help for a summary of these and other options.)
